# DataGridView DataSource not updating with SelectAll checkbox method

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have the following code that runs on the `CheckedChanged` event of a checkbox.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determine whether to select all order records
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">determine sender object</param>
/// <param name="e">event args</param>
private void CbSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dgvOrderLines.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        bool value = this.CbSelectAll.Checked;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.dgvOrderLines.RowCount; i++)
        {
            this.dgvOrderLines[0, i].Value = value;
        }

        if (value)
        {
            this.btnFailed.Enabled = true;
            this.BtnDownload.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.btnFailed.Enabled = false;
            this.BtnDownload.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this doesn't seem to actually update the underlining `DataSource`. The checkbox column that it loops through visually updates fine.

So when I do the following, after a user presses a button, the selected rows all still have a false value in the checkbox column.

```
Order[] orderlines = ((SortableBindingList<Order>)this.dgvOrderLines.DataSource).Where(x => x.Include == true).ToArray();
```

Any idea's as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: As a note, I've tried things like `EndEdit()`, `CommitEdit()`, etc. after the loop without any success.

Comment: Could you post the aspx page too?

Comment: Why not just update the underlying datasource with the value?

Comment: @UWSkeletor Dammit, I hadn't even though about trying that. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the above method was working perfectly fine.

Coming back to it after the weekend I see that oddly the method is being called before we process the stuff we want, not after.

It was a case of resetting the gui for new data too early.